Can't use WiFi in Linux Mint
I'm new to Linux, I'm using Linux Mint in dual-boot with Windows 11, and for some reason I can't use WiFi in Linux Mint.
I've disabled Secure Boot in UEFI and Fast Startup in Windows 11, but it doesn't work.
I have an ACER Aspire 3 15, with a Linux Mint uname -r returns 6.8.0-45-generic
Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?
return of lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Root Complex (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge (rev 02)
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h Internal PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h Internal PCIe GPP Bridge
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1724
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1725
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1726
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1727
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1728
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1729
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 172a
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 172b
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: ADATA Technology Co., Ltd. SM2P41C8 NVMe SSD (DRAM-less) (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mendocino (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 19h PSP/CCP
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1503
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1504
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 6f)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
04:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1505


Please run lspci (if internal, otherwise lsusb) in order to identify your WiFi chipset, then [edit] the question and copy/paste the full line with the identification.

Thank you for adding the requested information. I've now edited with several corrections - BTW, you should accept it as soon as convenient - but the only information that matters is 02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902  (the "full line" meant the line identifying your WiFi device, obviously). Now the bad news: Mediatek 7902 is and always has been problematic in Linux.

If i change to other linux dist like ubuntu or kali, you think would be easier to fix this issue or is this a all Linux dist problem?

No...............

Definitely not Kali! Whatever you do, do not move to Kali! That isn't a normal distro, it is a specialized tool for pentesting and is much harder to use and configure, it even ships with networking disabled, so pelase don't use it unless you are a professional working in the field. As for your device, it does look like it isn't supported: MT7902 driver for Ubuntu

I gave Kali as option cuz I'v used it in a friends notebook before, but ok, basically I cant do anything to use wifi in Linux (beside using a USB with my phone)

You don't need additional hardware if the end goal is to connect with a phone, just do USB tethering with a cable. Much more convenient (if you ignore the cable, of course) and stable.
